# Apache RedirectMarch on exact subfolder name not matching exact file extention

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

Trying to make one Apache .htaccess file with an regexp redirect for every access on exact named sub-folder and file that is not with exact/allowed extension

Currently trying to do it with RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch ^.*\/foderIneed\/.*(?!log)$
```

If it cointain subfolder with name foderIneed i need to deny access on other then .log files

```
/folder/foderIneed/folder2/file.log

/folder/foderIneed/folder2/folder2/file.log

/folder/folderX/foderIneed/folder2/folder2/file.log

/folder/foderIneed/folder2/file.html

/folder/foderIneed/folder2/folder2/file.php

/folder/folderX/foderIneed/folder2/folder2/file.sh
```

should mach and deny access to:

```
/folder/foderIneed/folder2/file.html

/folder/foderIneed/folder2/folder2/file.php

/folder/folderX/foderIneed/folder2/folder2/file.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
^.*?\/foderIneed\/[^.]+?\.(?!log).*$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `.*?` - Match anything except newline zero or more time.
- `[^.]+?` - Match one or more character other than `.` (lazy mode)
- `(?!log)` - Negative look ahead. Do not match `log`.
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OYZtHP/3/)